# Trouble in Installation of grouplens data at mahout

Tags: windows, cygwin, mahout

At the task of installation of mahout by link (http://girlincomputerscience.blogspot.com/2010/11/apache-mahout.html)

at the process of copying liberary to task-web folder .i am getting error like this..

for command

```
cp ../examples/target/grouplens.jar ./lib
error: cp: cannot stat 'cp ../examples/target/grouplens.jar' No such file or directory..
```

its not found grouplens.jar to target folder..

Thanks in Advance....

vignesh

Answer (score 2):

The message means what it says: the file `grouplens.jar` does not exist there. Have you built the code with `mvn install`? that's a previous step that should generate this JAR file. What version of Mahout?

Answer (score 0):

you are folowing the tutorial, but it is outdated - you were using newer versions of mahout than in the tutorial itself.

anyway, i also got stacked in the same position you were and there is no solution to it. no compilation or whatever will create the `.jar` file anymore.